# C programming sorting an array of structs based on 4 strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting, struct

*EDIT*:
I forgot to mention it begins as a Circular Linked List!

---

I need to sort my Array of Contact Structs, defined below, in the following order:

Last Name
First Name
Email
Phone Number

1. How would I go about this, in an efficient way?
2. Which sorting method would be the best fit, in terms of Big O order?

Here is my struct definition:

```
struct contact {
    char firstName[256], lastName[256], email[256], phoneNumber[256];
    struct contact *pPrev;
    struct contact *pNext;
};
```

Comment: Use qsort? What's the problem?

Comment: just use any sorting algorithm you want and change the criteria when you get two identical records; worst case scenario you'll change the criteria 3 times for the same two records.

Comment: How would I sort on 4 strings, with precedence of lastname over first and so on?

Comment: In order from left to right. Also I don't know where you've seen a 256 character long phone number. And your little structure can't hold the names of 3/4 of the people in this world. I question your design.

Comment: @GeorgeG. just order for last name until you get two or more identical last names for which you apply the next criteria....

Comment: @Blindy - the assignment says each field can be up to 255 chars long... thus 256th for a null terminate char...

Comment: To everyone who downvoted this: Downvoting a post like this (where I am still learning to program and did my homework, searching for another post like it and searching google before posting) Cheapens this website, making it essentially a coder's Reddit!!! I came here with a real problem and didn't know the answer, hoping to get help... Instead, most of you downvote me immediately, leaving me still not understanding a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your data is organized in a list (due to pPrev and pNext). qsort() cannot be used on lists.

For lists Mergesort is the way to go: As long as the list contains more than one element, split it into two lists, sort each of them, then merge the two sorted lists into one: Since both lists are sorted only the heads have to be compared. Compare the heads of the two lists, remove the smaller one and append it to the sorted list.

Complexity is O(N*log N)

Comment: My question is (and I am probably mistaken, just trying to understand): how do I determine in what order/ what to sort against what? wouldn't this algorithm leave me with a sorted list in some places, and an unsorted one in others? Like as in, if its just adding to the end, how would it case for if it belonged in between the two elements?

Comment: It can never belong somewhere in between since the two lists you are merging from are already sorted, i.e. if you remove a node from one of those two lists, none of the remaining nodes is lower than the removed one.

Comment: so you essentially finding the minimum/maximum, and saying it is sorted?

Comment: Yes. Wikipedia has more information including some code for sorting lists. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort